# Angular toggle filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display some data using a `ng-repeat`. I want to have a filter on the displayed data and when I click on a specific item the filter should be removed. When I click again on that specific item, the filter should be added again.

I've started with an idea, in my view I have:

```
<ion-item class="row" ng-repeat="t in tickets">
    <div class="col" ng-click="toggleFilter(t.name)">{{t.name}}</div>
</ion-item>
```

In my controller:

```
.controller('TicketCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.toggleFilter = function (name) {
        name = $filter('getSlice')(name);
        alert(name);
    }
});
```

When I alert the `name` it gives the correct filtered item, but it's not updating in the view. I think this has to do something with a child scope of the `ng-repeat`, but I don't know how to do this with toggling a filter.

Does anyone has any suggestions or a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify further how your filter is supposed to work? Currently your `toggleFilter` function isn't doing anything useful except reassigning the value of the `name` variable that is passed in as a parameter.

Comment: @djskinner my filter just takes an input and slices that input to give an output with maximum 20 characters and adds '...' to the end. The filter is working when I alert `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not updating in the view, beacause in $scope.toggleFilter you are modifying a local variable not binded with the view, in that list angular is binded with your $scope.tickets variable so you should modify the binded variable directly to see your changes in the view, you could achive this using the $index iterator variable available when you use ngRepeat
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

The result should be something like this:

-view:

```
<ion-item class="row" ng-repeat="t in tickets">
    <div class="col" ng-click="toggleFilter(t.name, $index)">{{t.name}}</div>
</ion-item>
```

-controller:

```
.controller('TicketCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.toggleFilter = function (name, index) {
        $scope.tickets[index].name = $filter('getSlice')(name);
        alert(name);
    }
```

PS Off topic: I see that you are using ionic framework, if you are going to use ng-repeat in mobile devices the performance is going to be much better if you use the collection repeat directive, mobile devices doesn't perform smooth when you scroll long lists of elements with ng-repeat  because de 2 way binding of angular. 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With the use of `index` I could make it work. To toggle I  saved the original data in an array and I also have an array to check if the specific item should get the filter true or false. Oh and I had to add `track by $index` to the `ng-repeat`. Edit: Also thanks for the tip about collection-repeat. But I actually don't use big amounts of items in my lists, I think maximum 10 items or so per list. Is it still beneficial then?

Comment: Glad it helped, in older devices you will notice scrollling a little bit  smoother. But in newer devices you definitely won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to keep a track of the state of the row (clicked or not clicked). Ideally you do not want to change the scope property's name.

The following code should work for you

```
<ion-item class="row" ng-repeat="t in tickets" ng-click="t.clicked=!t.clicked">
    <div class="col" ng-if="t.clicked">{{t.name | getSlice}}</div>
    <div class="col" ng-if="!t.clicked">{{t.name}}</div>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a nice solution and was also my initial solution. Only problem I got with this was that on some older devices you saw both divs for a milisecond or so at the same time, this is what I wanted to prevent. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and create a wrapper:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <button ng-click="toggleFilter()">Toggle Filter</button><br/>
        <span ng-repeat="item in data | filter:myFilter">
            {{item}}<br/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app',[]).
controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    $scope.shouldRunFilter = false;

    $scope.myFilter = function(item){
        if($scope.shouldRunFilter)
        {
            return item > 5;
        }

        return item;
    }

    $scope.toggleFilter = function(){
        $scope.shouldRunFilter = !$scope.shouldRunFilter;
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b7u068jq/).

Comment: I don't know but now the filter is going to be applied to **all** items within the `ng-repeat`. I only want this for specific items. I'm working on a solution right now using Javier Abrego's idea. Anyways I used your `shouldRunFilter` check, so thanks for that!